# How can read file with unreadable file name?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to read some email files. But they have a strange format in their name, like this.

[image]

This is the result after I try to read their name by python

[image]

And this is the problem when I try to work with them.

[image]

This is my code:

```
import email
import os
import sys
import fnmatch

# Path to directory where attachments will be stored:
path = sys.argv[1]
# List files
listing = os.listdir(path)

for fle in listing:
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(fle, u'*.eml'):
        with open(path + fle, 'rb') as f:
            msg_content = email.message_from_file(open(path + fle))
            print msg_content
```

My OS is Window 10

How can I read their names and their contents?
Thank you.

Comment: It could be more an OS related issue than a Python one.

Comment: Yes, I really don't know what is the problem. Can you suggest one @BasileStarynkevitch?

Comment: Do you *really*, absolutely need to use Python 2 for this?

Comment: Also, it's unclear what `email.message_from_file` is. Make your code sample *complete* first.

Comment: @Tomalak, Python2 or python3 are OK with me. And I think `email.message_from_file` is clear enough, because I just try to print out the content of email files.Or you can imagine that I want to `print msg_content['To']`

Comment: If you have both versions of Python, use Python 3 for this. Open the file with the correct encoding, you are not currently doing that.

Comment: Can you give me an example as an answer, I feel a little bit silly here. :p @Tomalak

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for my issue.

Compressing all files and read directly from zip files.

Example, I compress all email messages to `emails.zip`. Then I use `zipfile` library to read it.
This is my code:

```
 import email
 import os
 import sys
 import zipfile

 # Path to directory where attachments will be stored:
 path = sys.argv[1]
 # List files
 listing = os.listdir(path)

 for fle in listing:
     name = str(fle.lower())
     if name.endswith('.zip'):
        print '\n++++++++++++++ {} ++++++++++++++'.format(name)
        filepath = path + fle
        zfile = zipfile.ZipFile(filepath)
        for fname in zfile.namelist():
            data = zfile.read(fname)
            emailname = os.path.basename(fname).lower()
            if emailname.endswith('.eml'):

                msg_content = email.message_from_string(data)
                if msg_content['to'] is not None:
                    receiver = msg_content['to']
                elif msg_content['reply-to'] is not None:
                    receiver = msg_content['reply-to']
                else:
                    receiver = ''
                print emailname, receiver
```

I hope it can help anyone when they have the same issue.